# ERROR 1215 (HY000) at line 13: Cannot add foreign key constraint

Tags: mysql, foreign-keys

I get the following error:

```
ERROR 1215 (HY000) at line 13: Cannot add foreign key constraint
```

for the following query:

```
ALTER TABLE client_generique
ADD CONSTRAINT client_generique_boutique_id_boutique_id
FOREIGN KEY (boutique_id) REFERENCES boutique (id)
  ON DELETE SET NULL;
```

The `boutique.id` is a `primary key unique not null`.

The phpmyadmin structure export of the boutique table is this:

```
--
-- Table structure for table `boutique`
--

CREATE TABLE `boutique` (
  `id` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
  `nom` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `identifiant_site` varchar(8) NOT NULL COMMENT 'the eight number identifier from the bank',
  `certificate` varchar(255) NOT NULL COMMENT 'changes according to the mode, this will be used as salt in the sha1 that will be sent to the bank as the ''signature''',
  `mode` varchar(10) NOT NULL COMMENT 'is the ''vads_ctx_mode'': TEST or PRODUCTION',
  `payment_system` varchar(10) NOT NULL COMMENT 'CYBERPLUS OR PAYZEN for the new payment system added in end 2014'
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

--
-- Indexes for table `boutique`
--
ALTER TABLE `boutique`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  ADD UNIQUE KEY `unique_mode_per_identifiant_idx` (`identifiant_site`,`mode`);
```

I do not understand. What is the reason? How to solve this problem?

Comment: Using clear sentences is very useful, it is not your school exercise booklet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for Philipp Dietl for the solution.

It's not possible to add a foreign key constraint with a set null on delete on a not null column.

I've just modified the `boutique_id` column to a `BIGINT` (but no `BIGINT NOT NULL`).

Answer (score 0):

Could it be that your table `client_generique` stores values in `boutique_id` which do not exist in your table `boutique`?
Since you try to establish a reference to `boutique` the values must exist in that table.

Comment: I've just added the `boutique_id` column, so it's empty : 
`ALTER TABLE client_generique
ADD COLUMN label VARCHAR(255),
ADD COLUMN secret VARCHAR(32) ,
ADD COLUMN site_id VARCHAR(32) ,
ADD COLUMN boutique_id BIGINT NOT NULL,
DROP COLUMN site_marchand_id;`

Comment: maybe the data types are the problem. You use bigint(20) for id in boutique and use bigint in your alter-statement for the table client_generique

Comment: I've tried this whithout success : `ALTER TABLE client_generique  DROP boutique_id; ALTER TABLE client_generique
ADD COLUMN boutique_id BIGINT(20) NOT NULL; ALTER TABLE client_generique ADD CONSTRAINT client_generique_boutique_id_boutique_id
FOREIGN KEY (boutique_id) REFERENCES boutique(id)
  ON DELETE SET NULL;` So the data types may no be the problem.

Comment: Have you tried to add the constraint without the `on delete set null` argument? I guess that causes the problem here, because you define the column as `bigint(20) not null` which means it cannot be in the state `null` after deletion of the original value in boutique.

Comment: Thank you Philipp, that's the solution. That's so obvious and so logical that I missed it !